# Jmeter sending email to simulate cjsm (secure) doesn't use Base64 encoding for attachment

Tags: jmeter, smtp, base64

I am trying to simulate email from a secure email account using Jmeter.

Any attachments that I send are not being encrypted using Base64 as the emails are when sent from the same email address manually. this is causing a problem whereby the application that picks up the attachment to process fails to decode the email.

How can I get Jmeter to submit the email with attachment with content-transfer-encoding of base64?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is to perform [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoding of the message body - you can perform it via [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) available via [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle and can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/).

However be aware that it can be easily decoded back even using [online tools](https://www.base64decode.org/) so I doubt that it makes sense to rely on Base64 for security.

You can always call underlying [Java Mail API](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) functions from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) if JMeter cannot fully fulfill your requirements.